# Array Formula to Find Multiple Criteria and Return Multiple Matches

Tags: google-sheets

I know I can do this with a query, but I don't want to have a formula on each line (my original spreadsheet has 1000+ lines).  I'd rather do it with an array formula.
I am trying to find student records that match a student number and a course number.  This would be easy enough to do with vlookup but many students take a course multiple times so I want it to potentially return multiple results.

Student # is ColA, course title is ColB.  In F4 I want an array formula that will go down ColF, match the student number, and return matches (in ColF and ColG) that correspond to a course code (in this case, ENG30* (matches could be ENG301, ENG302, ENG303...).

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uolqhzO4weWak3zQL0StqGiBDZnP0GduPoWwusK30Qo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you mean by "I know I can do this with a query, but I don't want to have a formula on each line "? Query will have only one formula in one line.

Comment: If I want a match for each student number, I would have to have a query formula for each line, yes?  Judging by your response I'm obviously mistaken

Comment: so how do you do it?

Comment: Thank you! Quick question: what tweak would need to be made if there were more than two instances of ENG40*? Let's say there were as many as 12?

Comment: Your question may be quick. But,There is no quick answer. You should've included this in your first question. The formula I  made already has plenty of tricks, tweaks and work to put this in a format that you requested. To modify it again for 12 instances would need plenty more work. Next time, ASK clearly. Make your requirements very clear at the beginning. Try figuring this out yourself.  Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. It's a website to ask your questions when the code you've tried doesn't work.  Your attitude here is very demeaning. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:`F4`=

```
=QUERY(A1:B25000,"Select A,B where B contains 'ENG30'",1)
```

***EDIT:***

K4:

```
=QUERY(A1:B25000,"Select A,B where B contains 'ENG30' and A matches '"&JOIN("|",E4:E446)&"' order by A",1)
```

M4

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K4:K250=K5:K251,L5:L251,""))
```

F4

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4:E446,K4:M245,{2,3},0)))
```

Comment: Mark this as solution by clicking ✔ on the left of this post.